# Eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

Why is it that if $Ax=\lambda x$ and $A^*x=\mu x$ then $\lambda = \overline{\mu}$?

I tried to say $(Ax,x)=(\lambda x,x)=\lambda(x,x)$ and $(Ax,x)=(x,A^*x)=(x,\mu x)=\overline{\mu}(x,x)$. This, I think, shows why the implication holds. But I don't understand why $(x,\mu x)=\overline{\mu}(x,x)$, since I think $(\lambda x,x) = \lambda(x,x)$. I might be completely wrong but I dont understand this. Especially because the "$(\,,)$" notation is just the inner product? So I like to think more in this notation

$$(Ax,x)=(Ax)^Tx=(\lambda x)^Tx=\lambda x^Tx$$

But wouldn't it be $^*$ in this case, not $^T$? I don't understand though, with this notation, where $(Ax,x)=(x,A^*x)$ comes from since

$$(Ax,x)=(Ax)^Tx=x^TA^Tx=(x,A^Tx)=x^TA^*x=x^T\mu x=\mu x^Tx$$

So here $\mu=\lambda$? But I learned $^*$ is pretty much just $^T$ but with the conjugate taken on every entry.

Im obviously missing something, can someone please explain this how the first connects to the second notation? Whenever I read the general inner product I translate it back to just matrix multiplication and stuff, so when I don't understand that one I'm just using the rules like a parrot without any understanding of what's happening.

Please help me see where things are going wrong. Any help better formulating this question is also apreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should read the [Wikipedia page on inner products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using complex vectors and matrices, you should be using "conjugate transpose" $*$ throughout, and never the usual transpose. So the inner product is $\langle v, w \rangle := v^* w$. (You could also define it as $\langle v, w\rangle := w^* v$ instead, it does not make too much of a difference. Just pick one and stick to it.)

In terms of the inner product, note that we have, in general, $\langle cv, w \rangle = \bar{c} \langle v, w \rangle$ and $\langle v, cw \rangle = c \langle v, w \rangle$. This is called "sesquilinearity", which is part of the [definition of an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

---

For your proof:

In terms of vectors and matrices, we have
$$x^* A x = x^* (Ax) = x^* (\lambda x) = \lambda x^* x$$
and
$$x^* A x = (A^* x)^* x = (\mu x)^* x = \bar{\mu} x^* x.$$

You can also rewrite this entirely using inner products and applying the sesquilinearity property.

Comment: Isn't it $\langle cv, w \rangle = c \langle v, w \rangle$ and $\langle v, cw \rangle = \bar{c} \langle v, w \rangle$? Thats what wiki says. Does it matter how you define this though? But then also why is this the case since this IS a vector space so shouldnt $\langle v, w \rangle = \langle w, v \rangle$?? Using this then everything just breaks. Also why use the angle bracket notation if it can define just one operation. I can write $A^TB^*C^{-1}D$ given that the dimensions work out if I want, but can you represent it with the $\langle \rangle notation?

Comment: @Goob This is the difference between $\langle v, w \rangle := w^*v$ and $\langle v, w \rangle := v^* w$ in the case of the inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Sorry I picked the one that was different from Wikipedia. It does not matter too much as long as you are consistent. And note that the condition is $\langle v, w \rangle = \overline{\langle w, v \rangle}$. For your second question, the short answer is "probably not," but one usually is not in a situation where you need to do a regular transpose and a conjugate transpose.

Comment: @Goob $\langle v, w \rangle$ is only equal to $\langle w , v \rangle$ when you are dealing with real vector spaces, in which $\langle v, w \rangle = \overline{\langle w , v \rangle} = \langle w , v \rangle$.

Comment: Hey sorry for bothering again but something seems strange. If I define $\langle A,B \rangle =A^*B$ then if I write $\langle Ax,y \rangle =(Ax)^*y=x^*A^*y=x^*(A^*y)=\langle x, A^*y \rangle, $ which is great. But then also under this definition $\langle \lambda x,y \rangle =\lambda \langle x,y \rangle$. But this means that $(\lambda x)^*y=\lambda x*y$, and $\langle x,\lambda y \rangle = x^*(\lambda y)=\overline{\lambda}x*y=\overline{\lambda}\langle x,y \rangle $. What on earth is this??? $(\lambda x)^*=\lambda x*$ and $(\lambda y)=\overline{\lambda}y$? What magic is this?

Comment: @Goob If you define $\langle v, w \rangle = v^*w$ then $\langle \lambda x, y \rangle = (\lambda x)^* y = \bar{\lambda} x^* y = \bar{\lambda} \langle x, y\rangle$. Similarly, $\langle x, \lambda y \rangle = x^* (\lambda y) = \lambda x^* y  = \lambda \langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: Ok. How would you show that $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,A^* y \rangle$ with the definition $\langle Ax,y, \rangle = (Ax)y^*$ since we want to put that into $x(Ay)^*$ I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Goob $(Ax) y^*$ is a matrix, not a scalar. If you meant $\langle v, w \rangle := w^* v$, then $\langle Ax, y\rangle = y^* (Ax)$ and $\langle x, A^* y\rangle = (A^* y)^* x = y^* (A^*)^* x = y^* A x$.

Answer (score 1):

for a rather simple take, you can use Schur Triangularization and compute the same thing two different ways.
With unitary  $V := \bigg[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}\mathbf x & \mathbf v_2 &\cdots & \mathbf v_{n}\end{array}\bigg]$

$A = VRV^{-1}= VRV^* =V\begin{bmatrix} \lambda &  \mathbf b_{n-1}^*\\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf R_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}V^*$

For simplicity assume $\big \Vert \mathbf x \big \Vert_2=1$, then
$\mu\mathbf x= A^*\mathbf x= V\begin{bmatrix} \overline{\lambda} & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf b_{n-1} & \mathbf R_{n-1}^* \end{bmatrix}V^*\mathbf x=V\begin{bmatrix} \overline{\lambda} & \mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf b_{n-1} & \mathbf R_{n-1}^* \end{bmatrix}\mathbf e_1= \overline{\lambda}\mathbf x +\sum_{k=2}^n b_{k-1} \mathbf v_k$
$\implies \mathbf 0 = \big(\overline{\lambda}-\mu\big)\mathbf x +\sum_{k=2}^n b_{k-1} \mathbf v_k$
$\implies $ all coefficients are zero by linear independence
$\implies \mu = \overline{\lambda}$

(note: this also implies, for some $j$, we have $\sigma_j = \vert \lambda\vert$ i.e.  the modulus of $\lambda$ is a singular value for $A$)